# My app crashed after Idling in heroku and i dont know why

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, strapi

Heroku say if app inactive after 30m, it will be idling, but i dont know why in my case,  it seem shut down instead of idling, and i must restart dynos to make it worked again , so annoying. Does anyone know what problem with me? This project started 10 months ago and just got this issue in 2 weeks ago. so i cannot have problem with my code.

[image]

Can solve this problem and know what cause this problem

Comment: What's in your `Procfile`? If you don't have one of those, please show us the scripts from  your `package.json`.

Comment: And please make sure to share the contents of those files, and any other logs you have, as [_text_, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577).